# Getting point from known points to specific distance of polyline using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, distance, .net, line

I want to know the coordinates of a polyline from specific point and distance.
I have attached image to clear the specification. 
say, I have a points B(2,3). I want to know the coordinates of A and C from 2 feet distance of B point. I have tried this:

```
public IPoint GetPointAtFrom(double distance, Coordinate givenCoordinate)
    {
        ArcGeometry.IPoint outletPoint = new ArcGeometry.PointClass();
        ArcGeometry.ICurve curve = _polyline;
        curve.QueryPoint(ArcGeometry.esriSegmentExtension.esriExtendTangentAtFrom, distance, false, outletPoint);
        return new Point(outletPoint);
    }
```

but it gives from point or others.

Any idea? I am using .net in arcgis 10.0

[image: Example]

Comment: What is ArcGeometry?

Comment: Is measure (M) enabled on your polyline featureclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use ICurve [QueryPointAndDistance](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/ARCOBJECTS-NET/COMPONENTHELP/index.html#/QueryPointAndDistance_Method/002m00000116000000/) to and get the `DistanceAlongCurve` value for your 'B' point.

Then call [ICurve.GetSubcurve](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/ARCOBJECTS-NET/COMPONENTHELP/index.html#/GetSubcurve_Method/002m00000110000000/) twice (with the `DistanceAlongCurve + 2` and `DistanceAlongCurve - 2`) and the `fromDistance` parameter as `0`. And the `asRatio` as `false`.

The "To" points of the resulting subcurves would be your 'A' and 'C'.

http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/ARCOBJECTS-NET/COMPONENTHELP/index.html#/GetSubcurve_Method/002m00000110000000/